# how to bubble-sort or build multi-dimensional arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, bubble-sort

I'm not sure how to phrase the question so instead I will copy/paste the prompt from my homework and hopefully that will make my question clear. I am very new to python and am almost totally lost in how to complete this task. The task is as follows:

I am stuck on part B.

> a. Three Strikes Bowling Lanes hosts an annual tournament for 12 teams Design a program that accepts each team's name and total score for the tournament and stores them in parallel arrays. Display the names of top three teams.
>
> b. Modify the bowling tournament program so that, instead of the team's total score, the program accepts the score of each of the four team members. Display the names of the five top scorers in the tournament as well as their team names

Here is what I have so far for part A, though I still cant get it to sort by the highest score while displaying the correct team name.

```
scores = range(0,12)

names = range(0,12)

teamScore = []

teamName = []

for names in names:
    name = input("Please enter the team name: ")
    teamName.append(name)
print("\n" + "Please enter the team scores here: ")
for scores in scores:
    score = input("Please enter the team score: ")
    teamScore.append(score)
result = sorted(zip((teamName, teamScore)))
print(result)
```

Comment: Try to solve part A and post your code here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but writing things like `for scores in scores` and `for names in names` is not good practice. because you are replacing your variable. `scores` at the end of the loop means something different from what it did at the beginning. Instead, consider doing something like `for s in scores` and `for n in names`.

Comment: Also note that as written your scores are `<class 'str'>` meaning they will be sorted as strings and `'10' > '2'` will return `False` because `1` is before `2` when sorted by "alphabetical order".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SO community!

This is obviously not a complete answer bit should help you make some progress.

```
count = 3  # Pretend there are only 3 teams for ease in debugging

names = []  # The team names (we don't need long names in a simple program)
for i in range(count):  # Do this for each of "count" teams.
    name = input("Please enter the team name: ")  # Get the name
    names.append(name)  # Add it at the end of the names list.
```

print(names)

Session output:

```
Please enter the team name: The Bulldogs
Please enter the team name: Strikers
Please enter the team name: Out of this world
['The Bulldogs', 'Strikers', 'Out of this world']
```

Try improving this as much as you can and come back with any questions.